# Prove the function f(x,y)= (Jx, Ky) is a homomorphism from G X H onto (G/J) X (H/K)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G and H be groups. J is a normal subgroup of G & K is a normal subgroup of  H.

I know that I would use the fundamental homomorphism thereom: Let f:G->H be a homomorphism of  G onto H. IF K is the kernel of f, than H=~G/K, and I would apply this to direct products but i dont know how.

Comment: At what point exactly are you having problems showing that function is a homomorphism?

Comment: Can you write down the equation(s) that express the fact that it is a homomorphism?